# Python Recursive function: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am writing an implementation of a graph where I have a Node class that can have one parent and many children. I wanted to include a method to get the set of ancestors of a certain Node and have written this as follow:

```py
     def ancestors(self) -> Set["Node"]:
         """Return all ancestors of this node.
 
         Returns
         -------
         Set
             The set of all ancestors to this node or, if this node has no
             parent, returns the empty list
         """
         if not self.parent:
             return set()
         return {self.parent}.update(self.parent.ancestors())
```

The following example shows the idea:

```py
a = Node()
b = Node()
c = Node()

a.parent = b
b.parent = c

a.ancestors()
```

This however throws the following error and I cannot figure out why

```
>       return {self.parent}.update(self.parent.ancestors())
E       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This method should never return None seeing as the default case returns an empty set. What is returning None in this scenario?

Comment: Can you provide the full implementation of the class? It would be easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is not in the default case (`return set()`) but actually in the recursive case. The method `Set.update()` updates the set in-place, but it returns `None`. You can see that here:

```
>>> x = set()
>>> y = x.update([5])
>>> print(x)
{5}
>>> print(y)
None
```

One way you could fix your code is, instead of using `.update`, use the union operator `|` as follows:

```
def ancestors(self) -> Set['Node']:
    if not self.parent:
        return set()
    return {self.parent} | self.parent.ancestors()
```